# Prove that a sequence is well defined

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

I would like to know how to prove that the sequence
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
a_1 &=& \ln(1) \\
a_2 &=& \ln(1\times \ln(2))\\
a_3 &=& \ln(1\times \ln(2 \times \ln(3))) \\
 & \vdots& \\
a_n &=& \ln(1\ln(1\times \ln(2 \times \ln(3\times ( \cdots (n-1)\times\ln(n))\cdots))) \\
 & \vdots &
\end{array}
$$
is well defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a sequnce of functions $f_n\colon [1,\infty)\to\Bbb R$ (for $n\ge 2$) as follows:
$$f_2(x)=\ln(2 x)$$
and for $n\ge 3$,
$$f_n(x)=f_{n-1}(\ln(nx)).$$
This is valid because for $n\ge 3$ and $x\ge 1$, we have $\ln(nx)>\ln e=1$, so $\ln(nx)$ is in the domain of $f_{n-1}$.
Now for $n\ge2$, your $a_n$ can nicely be written as
$$ a_n=\ln(f_n(1)).$$

Comment: I was looking for a proof like this. Thanks.